# Filtering AWS CloudWatch were some events are JSON and some are text

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am streaming log streams from a CloudWatch log group using a subscription filter, but I can't figure out how to properly filter the events. The following example will create a subscription filter in a log group for an Elastic Kubernetes Service (EKS) cluster. This log group contains 5x log streams.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  ClusterName:
    Type: String
Resources:
  TriggerEksControlPlane1:
    Type: AWS::Logs::SubscriptionFilter
    Properties: 
      DestinationArn: !Sub "arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:newrelic-log-ingestion"
      FilterPattern: "{ $.level != \"Metadata\" }"
      LogGroupName: !Sub /aws/eks/${ClusterName}/cluster
```

The issue is that one of the streams is formatted as JSON while the others are plain text. In this case, using the filter `{ $.level != "Metadata" }` results in events for the JSON log stream being streamed as expected, but no events from the other log groups are streamed at all. Testing the filter in CloudWatch confirms this.

So my question is... how can I write a filter that will find both non-JSON events, and JSON events where `{ $.level != "Metadata" }`?

Note that the docs seem to indicate that EKS is not capable of puting log streams into log groups that are not the default (`/aws/eks/${ClusterName}/cluster`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after sleeping on it, turns out you can use simple matching on JSON formatted logs. While the docs don't say that you can, I think it would be a good addition for AWS to specifically say that it does work.

So in my case, the following works to filter out JSON logs where `level = "Metadata"`, and to include text logs that I wouldn't expect to contain such text anyway.

```
-"\"level\":\"Metadata\""
```